# Drupal 7 Views - Show all terms in Taxonomy and nodes in content type that use that term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I am using the Views Pivot module (may not be relevant since I think my query is more views in general)

I want to put Subjects (Taxonomy) as row headings and Child Names (Another Taxonomy) as columns.

The data will be a Node title that where both the Subject and Child Name was selected.

The above works but only shows me the just those Subjects that have actually been used in the content type. I want to show every Subject and have a blank cell where the Subject has not been used in a node.

[image: Here is a mock up of what I tried to describe above]

Answer (score 0):

I want this exact same answering but I am using Views TableGroup module - but it appears it's the query itself that's the issue and not the module.

One way to go about your issue is to create the view from the perspective of the Subject - do you know how to list all your subjects out in a row in Views? That's something I'm struggling with at the moment - if you know how to do it your almost there.

You'd create your view with the Taxonomy: Subject field as the filter - then you would work in reverse so you'd pull any child name's that are linked via the content type.